# StackOverflowError exception in constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I received this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.AbstractCollection.<init>(AbstractCollection.java:66)
at java.util.AbstractList.<init>(AbstractList.java:76)
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
```

Does that mean a class can't contain objects of itself as a variable? But in a linked list implementation, a node can contain a node pointing to itself?

```
public class Test {

String name;
List<Test> related;

public Test() {

    name = "dog";
    related = new ArrayList<Test>();    
    related.add(new Test());
    related.add(new Test());
    related.add(new Test());
}

public List<Test> relate() {

    return related;
}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    for(Test t : test.relate()) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does `new Test()` do internally?

Comment: It not the problem with the calss having its Object as member variable in it,  I think it is because of recursive calling of Method, you should follow a logic which will exit recursive calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by adding a parameter to the constructor that specifies how many elements to add, demonstrating that the problem is unbounded recursion in your code, not an inherent problem in creating a new instance in a constructor:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  String name;
  List<Test> related;

  public Test(int numberToAdd) {

    name = "dog";
    related = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberToAdd; i++) {
      related.add(new Test(0));
    }
  }

  public List<Test> relate() {

    return related;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test(3);
    for (Test t : test.relate()) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor creates three new instances of itself, each of which creates three new instances, each of which creates three new instances and so on.

To fix it you should create two separate classes - one that implements the linked list and one to create and use your linked list.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Test() {

    name = "dog";
    related = new ArrayList<Test>();    
    related.add(new Test()); // Here, you can calling the constructor
    related.add(new Test()); // recursively within the constructor?
    related.add(new Test()); // Hence the StackOverflowError?
}
```

Don't think it has anything to do with a class containing objects of itself as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
package com.my.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

private String name;
private List<Test> related;

public Test(String name, int times) {
    this.name = name;
    related = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        related.add(new Test("child"+i, 0));
    }
}

public List<Test> relate() {
    return related;
}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test("parent", 3);
    for (Test t : test.relate()) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
}
```